# Краш Ubuntu при запуске Visual Studio Code или Atom

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ide, visual-studio-code, atom

Когда запускаю Visual Studio Code или Atom сразу вылетает система, просто выходит из пользователя, что делать?

Comment: Зачем Вы используете IDE для Windows под Ubuntu? Есть же тот же gedit или даже notepadqq

Comment: @Adokenai Для начала VS Code и Atom есть на Ubuntu, скачаны оба из Ubuntu Software

Comment: я не утверждаю, что эти программные продукты отсутствуют на *nix. Я интересуюсь, зачем использовать изначально windows-направленные приложения на *nix системах. Ответ на Ваш вопрос может быть простой переход на аналогичное ПО для используемой ОС.

Comment: @Adokenai Мне очень нужны именно эти приложения, хотябы одно из них

Comment: VSCode портабельный или установленный?

Comment: @Adokenai вы путаете [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) с [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/). 1-й IDE для Windows и Mac, второй легкий редактор - кроссплатформенный (исходники на GitHub), Atom - то же что и Visual Studio Code

Comment: @Vlad Spirin то есть VS Code  не имеет двух вариантов установки?... Хорошо, я самоудаляюсь.

Comment: @Adokenai пройдите по ссылкам, все поймете. Устанавливать можно несколькими путями, это же практически каждый знает. Но тут то вопрос не о том. И [Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) изначально писался на все системы, включая линукс-системы

Comment: Я пользуюсь Атомом и VSCode на Xubuntu около 3 лет и никогда с подобным не сталкивался. Скорее всего у вас что-то серьёзно поломано в системе. Советую переустановить. Если не поможет, тогда уже придётся копаться в логах. Насчёт gedit и notepadqq - они и  рядом не стояли. Утверждать что текстовые редакторы могут быть альтернативой для IDE (да ещё и лучшей) просто смешно.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Систему только что установил, редакторы тоже, все чистое

Comment: Раньше, какой-то период были глюки, при переходе на `snap`, но сейчас насколько я знаю эти проблемы уже решены. Сам не так давно устанавливал в Ubuntu 18.04 и все ок. Гляньте на системные процессы, что там.

Comment: Ксати, они через snap у вас установлены? Если да, то попробуйте сначала удалить программы вместе с snap (`sudo apt remove code atom snap*`), затем перезагрузиться и установить их, скачав deb пакеты с офсайтов.

Comment: VSCode основан на хромиум, хромиум работает? Непонятная ошибка, но возможно это не выход пользователя из сессии, а падение иксов (х сервера), причина тогда кроется в OGL, драйверах и видеокарте. Попытайся запустить vscode так: code --disable-gpu

Comment: Да, не только vscode, атом тоже основан на электроне. поищите ошибки в логах, например: `~/.config/Code/logs` или в системных логах, при помощи программы gnome logs (`sudo apt install gnome-logs`).

Comment: Тут такое полотно комментариев. Воспользуйтесь чатом для этих целей: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86833/linux

Comment: @АлександрБерезовский Все сработало с `--disable-gpu`, но не подскажете, как сделать это же самое только не вводить постоянно в консоль команду?

Comment: `--disable-gpu` - это костыль. Вам нужно установить правильный драйвер на видео карту. Но если у вас особый случай и других драйверов нет, то добавьте этот костыль в `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop`, но лучше скопируйте его сначала в `~/.local/share/applications` и там поправьте, чтобы изменения не сбросились после обновления.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### И так, приступим к решению проблемы

Возможен запуск без графической карты с помощью костыля в виде запуска программы с аргументом `--disable-gpu`, больше пройдясь по пунктам настроек нашел окошечко с драйверами, так вот, поменял разные драйверы (у меня их 3), в итоге подошел следующий вариант:
[image: Software & Updates Window]

Большое спасибо [Александру Березовскому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/318562/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) и [Beast Winterwolf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177630/beast-winterwolf) за активное участие в вопросе!