# Зависает редактор кода Atom

Tags: windows, atom

Почему после удаление некоторых не нужных драйверов (по типо откат драйвера интел - для проц., и амб - для видеокарты) программа Atom (редактор кода) перстал запускатся. Тоесть он как бы запускается, внизу пишется 'Rebuilding paths cache... 1820' висит так минуту и потом выдает сообщение 'Editor is not responding' и есть две кнопки - это подождать или закрыть. Я тыкал подождать раза 4, и на этот 4 раз открылся код и можно было его редактировать. В чем причина? Почему с первого раза он не дал редактировать код а завис? Не уш то из за драйверов? Может из за отката системы который я делал? Переустановка не помогает, удалял все файлы, тоже не помогает.

---

Windows 7 X64

---

Скриншоты

### [image: Какждый раз разное число]

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926130/191416 - не оно же?

Comment: У меня не выходит из сисетмы, а висит, а потом выдает ошибку что атом завис

Comment: Ну в том вопросе выяснили, что мешает графон. Ты у себя его пробовал отрубить при запуске?

Comment: А где он открубается? Я не очень понял решение того вопроса (
ru.stackoverflow.com/q/926130/191416)

Comment: Не подскажешь где хранятся установленные плагины, хотелось бы их сразу одной кучей установить, а не опять искать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решил! Оказывается после удаления она удалилась далеко не вся, она была кроме папки appdata всюду! Я ее вроде отвсюду удалил и она после повторной установки запустилась и все с начала пошло.